# How to estimate the number of nodes in a trie based on a dictionary of words?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, trie

Say I want to build a trie out of 800,000 Sanskrit "base" words (in Devanagari script), with 20 prefixes and 2,000 possible suffixes. Each word is anywhere from 1-20 characters, and prefixes/suffixes are from 1-4 characters. The alphabet size (of the [Devanagari script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari_(Unicode_block))) is roughly 50 unicode characters.

We could say that on average (perhaps), each word is about 6 or 8 characters, this includes the combination of prefix + base word + suffix, with an average of 4 or 5 different characters per word. *I am just making this up, I would have to do some programmatic analysis of the dictionary to really get more accurate, but it's beside the point.*

*(But I would like to apply the theory/equations to any combination of words/alphabets/systems, like in multiple other languages, so looking for the general approach, using this as an example).*

How do you estimate the rough size of the number of nodes in the corresponding trie? (Assuming 1 node is 1 unicode character).

It seems there are a few things you could calculate:

#### Theoretical min / max

Theoretical min or max of the number of nodes in the trie. This would assume you take every node as a unique character probably (max), or every node as the same character (min), and then somehow say something like:

```
min of shortest words:
800k words of 1 letter * 1 prefix of 1 letter * 1 suffix of 1 letter
(not sure how to calculate that even)
```

That would mean something like:

- combine the 800k words with a prefix (800k * 20 = 1.6m total), and combine each of those with a suffix (1.6m * 2000 = 3.2b?)

I am not doing this right....

#### Calculating min and max generally

Defining what min and max mean is kind of hard, so let me try and explain what I am feeling more.

- One min is assuming every letter is the same, and every thing is the shortest it can be (1 * 1 * 1). That isn't very useful I guess.
- Another value that would be more accurate, but it still feels vague to me, is to take an "average" of the possible values a word can take (each "base" word is 4 characters on average, and each suffix is 2 characters, and each prefix 1). Multiply that by 800k words and 20 prefixes and 2000 suffixes somehow, and you have a trie with some number of nodes.

That seems like it would give you a rough estimate of how many nodes will exist in the tree? Is there any straightforward way to calculate such a number? I am no math genius, but I do know the basics of combinatorics and such, from years ago of study for a few weeks.

Calculating a theoretical max would probably be useless as well, as that would mean every character would be different and be totally unlikely to happen in practice.

I am basically looking to estimate the number of nodes in the trie for a practical software application, so I can determine if my approach of creating an in-memory trie representation of the words (for Sanskrit, and many other languages) will be practical in terms of memory/object creation constraints in the programming language of choice.

I would like to get a rough but somewhat realistic ballpark estimate number to see more clearly what I'm dealing with.